# Google calendar API. Saying 403 error(insufficient permission)

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

```
{ 
  "error": { 
    "errors": [ 
      { 
        "domain": "global", 
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions", 
        "message": "Insufficient Permission" 
      } 
    ], 
    "code": 403, 
    "message": "Insufficient Permission" 
  } 
}
```

While inserting new event into google calendar.

Comment: Show the code which calls the calendar API

Comment: You app has insufficient permissions to insert into calendar. For example, if user did not give such permissions to your app, or you didn't login properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
{  
   "error":{  
      "errors":[  
         {  
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"insufficientPermissions",
            "message":"Insufficient Permission"
         }
      ],
      "code":403,
      "message":"Insufficient Permission"
   }
}
```

Means that the user you have currently authenticated with does not have permissions to insert your event.   Most of the Google Calendar API methods are private and there for can only be used by a user with the correct permissions.

1. Check the user you have authenticated with make sure that user has access to the calendar you are trying to insert events into.
2. Check the scopes you are authenticating with. If you are authenticating with read only access and trying to write you will also see this error.

Comment: Yes, this may be one the cause in other case but mine is different. But I the root of the issue. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

After some effort, I got the solution. I needed to delete all my previous credentials saved.

Example : I needed to delete ->.credentials/calendar-php-quickstart.json

where .credentials is a directory.